# Why are functions of compact support so important?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, intuition

1. Why are functions of compact support **so** important? Is there any relation between functions of compact support and coproducts?
2. [Olver](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4684-0274-2), mentions that if $f$ is in some function space with domain $\Omega$, then $f+ \epsilon \eta$ is in the same function space, so long as $\eta$ is of compact support in $\Omega$. Why is that?

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to know that you can "approximate" your function with compactly supported functions (compact support can be very important, for example we know that continuous function on a compact space is uniformly continuous).

Comment: You can think that functions of compact support are evidence your space is "sufficiently malleable", and this makes available a wider variety of tools when studying them.

Comment: It’s often the best replacement for theorems on compact spaces. E.g. $C(X)$ has as dual space all Borel measures on $X$ when $X$ is compact Hausdorff. For locally compact Hausdorff spaces we can prove something similar when we restrict the functions to compactly supported ones; these can always be integrated for finite Borel measures (these functions are bounded on compacta) and they’re closed under vector space operations, which is nice too in functional analysis. These functions are mainly used on locally compact spaces, because on those we have “enough” compact sets to do “useful” things.

Comment: Compactness is a really useful property for proving things. If a continuous function has compact support then you can use a compactness argument which is useful for proving lots of useful things. In some sense a function of compact support is useful because we scan prove lots of things about it. In another sense it captures the notion of “reasonable not super pathological or weird function” and that gives us some intuition as to why they might be useful